# schemeでリストの要素同士の積を求めるには

Tags: scheme

schemeで((商品番号a 価格a 購入個数a) (商品番号b 価格b 購入個数b)....)のようなリストを定義して、価格a*購入個数a+価格b＊購入個数b＋...のように、商品の総価格を求める関数を作りたいです。
どのように関数を書くべきでしょうか？

```
>(display (count-price '((1 100 10) (2 250 5) (3 500 3))))
```

```
#lang racket
(define (seki x y) ( * x y))

(define (count-price item)
  (if (null? item)
      `()
      ( apply + seki (map cadr item) (map last item))))
```

Answer (score 1):

関数 `seki` のパラメータをリストに変更します。

※ 入力値として要素数 3 の正整数のリストを前提としていますので、エラーチェックを追加する必要があるでしょう。

```lisp
(define (seki lst) (apply * (cdr lst)))

(define (count-price item)
  (if (null? item)
      `()
      (apply + (map seki item))))

(display (count-price '((1 100 10) (2 250 5) (3 500 3))))
=>
3750
```